# how browser knows end of reading data

Tags: go, sockets, https, tcp, proxy

I am trying to make a https proxy with Golang. I know at first, browser sends header with ending to `\r\n` and socket blocks `read()` until reading those character. But when it is encrypted(ssl/tls) and HTTP 1.1(keep connection alive)

- how Browser knows end of reading data?
- Do they read byte by byte and some special character at end(Is this a good way for large data at all?)?
- Or they send size of data first(as suggested in topics for tcp socket)?
- As proxy, how can I understand end of data when streaming or loading simple html page?

This is only part of code, it works when i run it in local network, but in server(vps) will block on read until connection closed. complete code [here](https://github.com/khordady/goroxy)

```
func write(client_to_proxy net.Conn, browser_to_client net.Conn) {
    defer client_to_proxy.Close()
    buffer := make([]byte, 1024)

    reader := bufio.NewReader(browser_to_client)

    for {
        length, err := reader.Read(buffer)
        if length > 0 {
            fmt.Println(time.Now().Format(time.Stamp) + " READ from client to browser: " + strconv.Itoa(length))
            //fmt.Println(string(buffer[:readLeng]))

            writeLength, err := client_to_proxy.Write(buffer[:length])
            if writeLength > 0 {
                fmt.Println(time.Now().Format(time.Stamp) + " WRITE from client to browser: " + strconv.Itoa(writeLength))
            }
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("ERR6 ", err)
                return
            }
        }
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("ERR5 ", err)
            return
        }
    }
}

func read(client_to_proxy net.Conn, browser_to_client net.Conn) {
    defer browser_to_client.Close()
    buffer := make([]byte, 1024)

    reader := bufio.NewReader(client_to_proxy)
    length, err := reader.Read(buffer)

    fmt.Println(time.Now().Format(time.Stamp) + " READ from proxy to client: " + strconv.Itoa(length))
    fmt.Println(string(buffer))

    if length > 0 {
        writeLength, err := browser_to_client.Write(buffer[:length])
        fmt.Println(time.Now().Format(time.Stamp) + " WRITE from client to browser: " + strconv.Itoa(writeLength))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("ERR7 ", err)
            return
        }
    }
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    go write(client_to_proxy, browser_to_client)

    for {
        length, err := reader.Read(buffer)
        fmt.Println(time.Now().Format(time.Stamp) + " READ from proxy to client: " + strconv.Itoa(length))
        //fmt.Println(string(buffer[:length]))
        if length > 0 {
            writeLength, err := browser_to_client.Write(buffer[:length])
            fmt.Println(time.Now().Format(time.Stamp) + " WRITE from client to browser: " + strconv.Itoa(writeLength))
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("ERR8 ", err)
                return
            }
        }
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
I use a client and server go app like this browser->client->proxy->so.com then so.com->prxoy->client->browser
I don't want encrypted data! my problem is at 'client' app, I don't know know how much should read bytes to unblock `read()`!

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding of how HTTPS works.  HTTPS isn't just encrypted HTTP requests and responses. It's an encrypted connection, over which standard HTTP requests and responses are sent.

Comment: @Flimzy I know what https is and I don't want to decrypt connection, I just try to know end of data to unblock read() and send it to browser. I added my complete github code

Comment: The point is, you can't know that at the TLS level.

Comment: @forootan A proxy is just a passthrough.  The browser tells the proxy which server to connect to, and then the proxy passes along whatever data the browser sends, and vice versa with whatever data the server sends back.  If the data is encrypted with TLS, the proxy CAN'T know what is in the data, since only the browser and server can decrypt it. All the proxy can do is pass raw bytes back and forth, until the TCP connection is closed. No more, no less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How Browser knows end of reading data?

By implementing the standard.

For HTTP/1.1 see [RFC 7230 section 3.3 Message Body Length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.3) for the details, how the length of the body is determined. Hint: based on information on the HTTP header, like Content-length and Transfer-Encoding.

> As proxy, how can I understand end of data when streaming or loading simple html page?

A proxy behaves the same regarding plain HTTP messages.

HTTPS traffic is passed through nd-to-end encrypted between client and server over the proxy using a tunnel. This tunnel gets created with a CONNECT request, which ends only with TCP connection close. The proxy has no insight into the connection and can thus also not determine where HTTP message header and body of the various requests and responses inside the encrypted traffic are.

Comment: but in https, all data are encrypted even header

Comment: @forootan: https with a proxy is done using the mentioned CONNECT request.

Comment: @forootan: I've made it clear that the proxy has no insight into the  HTTPS  and thus also not into requests and responses, headers and bodies.

Comment: OK I get your point Thanks. Browser reads header. What about stremed data lile vide? But still have problem and don't know size of data for read in proxy. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @forootan streaming media over HTTP/S still has to follow the HTTP standards, which includes the use of headers.  HTTP provides `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` to deal with sending data when the size is not known up front. But if the data is encrypted with TLS, there is no way for the proxy to see any of that, all it can do is pass along any raw bytes it receives from the browser and server, until the TCP connection is closed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes I understood that and fixed that problem with ```io.copy()``` in golang. I will make a complete described answer and put its code later. New problem is I can't reach blocked (in my country) web server like youtube even through proxy. I think it has some relation to dns but still trying. We have big GFW and this is like war for us.